# How to make my code decide which class to instantiate based on a parameter?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

I have a system in which I will perform queries to a database. I want Query1, Query2 and Query3 to use the same methods in their way to the data source layer.

To do that I would like to make something similar to [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) or [Template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) Patterns, where I have a part of the code which is a default behavior for all queries (getting to the database layer, connection, executing the query and so on) and a variable part (building the query itself).

I think this idea is good and feasible. I would receive a parameter from the client specifying the query to be built, build it and run. The only question is: given this parameter, how can I decide which method to call to build the query? This is my current solution: (is this solution a pattern?)

```
public Query QueryFactory(string queryIdentifier){
   if(queryIdentifier == "query1")
      return BuildQuery1();
   else if(queryIdentifier == "query2")
      return BuildQuery2(); 
}
```

It works, but I don't think this is "pretty enough", I would like something nicer. It would be perfect if it didn't require the developer to add a new if statement when he created a new query.
**Is there any way to improve this if/else chain? And to make this decision automatic?**

Edit:
The problem I want to solve is: I have queries that are going to be called against a database. I want to have the same flow so I don't have duplicated code for the queries that do not have any business logic applied to it (ex: get all users, get all students, and so on)

Comment: This smells suspiciously like Second-System Effect.  Can you be a little more specific about the particular problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: Sure, I have queries that are going to be called against a database. I want to have the same flow for the queries that do not have any business logic applied to it (ex: get all users, get all students, and so on)

Comment: Normally that's done with a Repository object.  You have CRUD methods for each domain object (users, classes, etc).  Sometimes those CRUD methods are code-genned.  Occasionally, someone will use a Generic Repository, which see.  BTW, Student is just a special case of User.

Comment: Sounds like you've got a standard FactoryMethod pattern. I don't see anything wrong with that (though, I usually prefer to us enums and a switch to identify which object to return).

Comment: If you can do meta-programming, then dynamically create an instance of the class, otherwise a `switch` statement could be prettier comparing to `if/else` statements -- and slightly faster. Also you didn't clearly mention what languages you're using. Your question could have different answers in different languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Steve Evers states, using an enumeration as a key and either a Class to instantiate (or an instance of Query pre-built) to return.  If you don't like the if/else pattern, I know Java has Map implementations, of which the EnumMap would be a good fit (where it optimizes the utilization of Enumerations as the key values in the map.

Then your code looks something like

```
public Query QueryFactory(QueryType type){
   return localMap.get(type);
}
```

With the assumption that you define an enumeration named QueryType, and your localMap contains the appropriate Query instances for each type.

If you didn't want to pre-instantiate the queries, the code would use the map to store the Class, which would allow the object to be instantiated then and there

```
public Query QueryFactory(QueryType type){
   Class queryClass = localMap.get(type);
   return (Query) queryClass.newInstance();
}
```

Again, this is all using Java as an example.  Just realized you didn't mention which language.  But it can be cleaned up the way it sounds like you would prefer.

Comment: Yes, I used string in my example for sake of simplicity, but the idea is to use an ENUM. Java is OK, the important is the concept, not the implementation. Thanks a lot :)